# Tab Bar titles not showing up on UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uitabbar

I'm working on adding forward and back buttons to the tab bar of my UIWebView, and the titles don't appear to be showing up.

Is there something wrong with the way I've initialized it? The tab bar itself appears, but it's blank.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"The url dude is: '%@'", _itemURL);

    // Initialize UIWebView
    self.myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                                 self.view.frame.size.height)];;
    self.myWebView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.myWebView];

    // Bottom Tab Bar (with back button)
    CGRect tabBarFrame = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 44, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 44);
    self.webViewTabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:tabBarFrame];

    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [self.webViewTabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [self.webViewTabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

    tabBarItem1.title = @"Back";
    tabBarItem2.title = @"Forward";

    [self.view addSubview:self.webViewTabBar];

// set the url
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_itemURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    // make url request
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) {
             [self.myWebView loadRequest:request];
             [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
         }
         else if (error != nil) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];

    [self.myWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];

}
```

Comment: Do you mean `UINavigationBar` which is on the top of the `UIView`? That's usually where back buttons go. If so, then you shouldn't be using the `UITabBarController`, rather you should be using `UINavigationController` which will automatically create a Back button for you when you push a `UIViewController` or `UIWebView` onto the stack.

Comment: @JaredH No I mean forward and back arrows on the bottom so that users can go back to a previous webpage in the `UIWebView`.

Comment: I think you may want to try a UIToolbar instead of a UITabBar. Try looking into that

Comment: @JoelBell That's a great point. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I almost don't want to post this code, out of fear of down votes (I think there is a better way to do this, but I'm just not sure of what it is), but it does work on all of my projects.

This adds a toolbar to the bottom of your screen which has buttons for navigating the webView forwards, backwards, and reloading (you'll have to write separate functions that handle these).

```
UIToolbar *bottomBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]init];
bottomBar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
bottomBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
bottomBar.translucent = NO;


[bottomBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height- 196, 320, 44)];



UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"<" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:webView action:@selector(goBack)];
UIBarButtonItem *forward = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@">" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:webView action:@selector(goForward)];
UIBarButtonItem *reload = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:webView action:@selector(reload)];
UIBarButtonItem *fake = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"   " style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];


bottomBar.items = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:fake,back,fake,fake, forward,fake,fake,fake,fake,fake,fake, reload, nil];
```

Of course, you'll have to modify this to fit your needs, but it does work for me. Like I said previously, I believe that there is a better way to do this, but I'm unsure of what that is. I would love if someone could point to a better method.

Comment: Instead of the fake item look into UIBarButtonItem's -initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action method. The two types that you want to mess with are UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace and UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace. They do what your trying to do here but much more elegantly. I'd advise updating the code with what you find there to avoid down votes ;)

Comment: @JoelBell Thanks for the suggestion. When I get a little more free time, I'll definitely look into that. The above code was based off of some production code, so I'm sure it could use an update.